# Why do my socket.io POST requests fail, while my GET requests do work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, polling

Oddly enough, the polling in the console on clientside shows 200 GET requests, but 404 POST requests. I have no idea what's going on. I already tried removing the CNAME thing off the http config file, and adding `{transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false}` to the client side code, but without success. Here is a little bit of my client side code:

```
const socket = io('//web.namei.nl',{path: '/demo/js/socket.io.min.js'},{transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false}).connect('', {query: `uuid=${getCookie('uuid')}&type=${getCookie('type')}` });
```

It seems to be a client-side problem, since GET requests do work.

[image]

Comment: you are using `websocket ` for the transport protocol, where does a HTTP POST come into the process?

Comment: The page I'm on is being posted, that's a signup form. When I do it from another webpage, which is not a signup, these are the errors: https://imgur.com/a/gz82MiT